# Input text from html to javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I don't understand how to make and use forms. Can someone give me and example using external java script where there is an input text and a submit button and when it gets click it does a java script function. I also have some questions. If i'm not using a form to change pages do i need a method. What do i put for the action attribute. Are forms the best way to get input text data to java script. And why should i use a form and not just input tags.
Thanks.

Comment: There are literally a million+ examples of that with a quick Google search.

Comment: you don't need `form` when you're using javascript, since it can read html content. go with jquery to make your life easier.

Comment: lol ok then what should i use to get text box to javascript

Comment: @SoursopTree i would somewhat disagree, while a form is not necessary, its better semantically to group together (and for screen readers) and the browser already preloads some functionality  to allow you to do things without writing more javascript code, its quite clear that the OP is new to development

Comment: very new :D can someone show me an example i looked at the ones on w3schools but they are kinda confusing and i want it to go to javascript

Comment: you will need to learn from the basic if you want to be able to move forward faster and don't want confusion. that's what everyone did.

Comment: "if i'm not using a form to change pages do i need a method", could you clarify this? do you mean that you don't want the page to change if you enter something and then submit?

Comment: yea on w3schools.com it always changes pages hwo do i just call a function

Comment: @SoursopTree which is why i'm advising against just going straight to jQuery and suggesting that keigo actually go through the motions of learning what form is, forms are very common and were around for much longer than jQuery

Comment: im not that new but can someone show me how to use a form and connect it to external javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need a form to collect user input form fields.

Here is a really simple friendly example using MagJS:

HTML:

```
<div id="hello">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input name="hello" placeholder="Enter a name here" />
  <hr/>
  <h1>Hello <name/></h1>
</div>
```

JS:

```
mag.module("hello", {
  view: function(state) {
    state.input = {
      _oninput: function() {
        state.name = this.value
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Here is a link to the working example: http://jsbin.com/fivaqoliqe/1/edit?html,js,output

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks but i dont use magjs is it possible to do that with just regular javascript?

Comment: You're very welcome, and yes absolutely, here is another example in regular JS: http://jsbin.com/rapiqaruku/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

The short of it is that W3Schools lets you play around but they are scarce on explanation so I suggest you check out this resource instead (which also has a demo of a form): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

The action attribute is where it should go after it is done to further process the form (typically a route or backend server is where you will go after). Given what you have been talking about however, you only have one field and one button, so you should look into the onclick attribute and then look up the input field and read the value. You use a form when you have a lot of inputs that are related and should be sent at once. There's a lot out there though as this is very basic but if you have any questions just ask.

Comment: thanks i already know how to use onclick but i didnt know i can use it with input fields!

Comment: @KeigoL please go through this tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms

Comment: also i would suggest to NOT worry about how the page refreshes because crawl before you walk. I would suggest it when you feel more comfortable with submitting forms, HTML and JS... When you think you can learn it Ajax is what you want to look up